# HTML semanctics Can elements come before heading tag in sectioning element?

Tags: html, semantics

Any HTML master out there please give me a GO.

Usually in sectioning element like `section` or `article`, `header` or `h1 ~ h6` tags stay prior to any element like following:

```
<section>
<header><h1>TITLE BLAH</h1></header>
<div>blah blah blah</div>
...
</section>
```

Can I just switch this order like this just for the sake of layout?

```
<section>
<div>blah blah blah</div>
...
<header><h1>TITLE BLAH</h1></header>
</section>
```

I know it doesn't make sense if this were the actual book.

I am stuck now...

Comment: yes you can switch it if that's your requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I can GO now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The header is what it contains and not where it's placed in the structure. http://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-header-element

> The header element represents a group of introductory or navigational
>   aids.
>
> A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading
>   (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element), but this is not required. The
>   header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents,
>   a search form, or any relevant logos.